# How does the Chime SDK and Amazon Transcribe integration work in terms of cost and transcription ending

Tags: amazon-transcribe, aws-chime-sdk

For my product I've integrated the chime sdk as our webrtc media server/meeting management and that's been great. We hooked in amazon transcribe with the built in integration. The problem is there seems to be a lot of hidden/undescribed functionality with this integration that drives cost up significantly. Does anyone know:

1. When using transcribe with the chime sdk with live transcription, when does the meeting end? Is there not automatic ending anymore when everyone leaves the meeting? It seems to run for the max 24hrs even though the default in the chime sdk docs is that it ends shortly after there being no more users in the call.
2. Does transcribe charge by the minute for however long the meeting is times the number of channels/people, even when it's 90% silence? It's hard to parse exactly, but I think even with 100% silence, it's charging to transcribe each channel so if you have 3 people join a call and only one talking, it's still 3x the number of minutes that the call is running.
3. Are there any recommended best practices for getting a list of the currently active meetings? Since they aren't auto-ending, I wanted to go through and close meetings off manually, but realized there is no list api call for the chime sdk functionality (CLI/AWS SDK/Console) so that you can see if there are any active meetings. I'm going to start tracking them myself, but it would be nice to have an AWS-backed way of catching if something is running that you aren't aware of.

Note: For some interesting additional information, someone from the chime team seems to concur in a github issue that auto-meeting end breaks when using media pipelines: "For media pipeline attendee, it is a muted empty audio stream but it is still counted as an attendee. So in your case you would need to listen to event where all attendee leaves then stop the media pipeline meeting manually." source: https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/issues/2454

Since the integration is AWS service to AWS service, I would hope this was better documented and handled these cases better.